# Wordpress while loop exclude those pages which have not children

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using that code to get all parent pages, all pages are top level. I am looking to exclude those pages which have not child pages.

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
));
if ($my_query - > have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query - > have_posts()) {
        $my_query - > the_post();

        echo get_the_ID().
        "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `the_post()` does, as well as `get_the_ID()`?

Comment: that code giving you all the list of parent and echo get_the_ID() is printing pages id. so you can get the data from those pages.

Comment: But you're not calling `get_the_ID()` on anything, you're executing it as if it were a private function, so what would be the result of that function? Can you post what your current script is giving as a result?